# replicate/duplicate/clone a mysql_result object

Tags: php, mysql, object, clone

I'm trying to save into file a mysql SELECT query as follows:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

$out = fopen('tmp/csv.csv', 'w');
while ($row = $result -> fetch_row()) {
fputcsv($out,$row);
    }
fclose($out);
```

after save I need to publish on a page as follows :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
//embed html code
}
```

The problem is that anytime I run $result->fetch_row(), a record of data is lost. I need to be able to run fetch_object at least 2   times within my code and preserve the data. I thought cloning would be a good solution for this, but it isn't.

Any hints, other that doing 2 query on the sql database ?

Answer (score 4):

I believe another solution that could work is to use `mysqli_data_seek`.

The mysqli_result object is a pointer that moves through the data with each call of fetch_row(), but you can move the pointer back to the beginning by calling

```
mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
```

And now the result is "reset", as it were, and you can use it again.

Learn more here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

Comment: this is working, also is the the simplest way due to the fact that need no patch, all the old code remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to re-use the data, load it into an array - or do all the logic in the same loop.

So for example,

```php
$data = []:
$result = $mysqli->query("...");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

$out = fopen('tmp/csv.csv', 'w');
foreach ($data as $row) {
    fputcsv($out, $row);
}
fclose($out);

// ...

foreach ($data as $row) {
    //embed html code
}
```

Or do it all in the same loop (this may not always be possible, so if it isn't, go with the option above).

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

$out = fopen('tmp/csv.csv', 'w');
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    fputcsv($out,$row);
    // embed HTML

}
fclose($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `mysqlind` installed as part of your PHP MySQL infrastructure, Use a `fetch_all()` to get all the results into an array. You can then use that array as many times as you like.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$all_results = $result->fetch_all();

$out = fopen('tmp/csv.csv', 'w');

foreach ( $all_results as $row){
    fputcsv($out,$row);
}
fclose($out);

// now to reuse the array for your HTML output
foreach ($all_results as $row) {
    //embed html code
}
```

Then you can reuse `$all_results`

If you dont have `mysqlind` then write a simple loop to load an array manually with all the results from the resultset

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$all_results = [];
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $all_results[] = $row;
}

$out = fopen('tmp/csv.csv', 'w');

foreach ( $all_results as $row){
    fputcsv($out,$row);
}
fclose($out);

// now to reuse the array for your HTML output
foreach ($all_results as $row) {
    //embed html code
}
```